# Is it possible to open a password-protected ODT document if the exact password was forgotten?

Tags: password, libreoffice

I have a long password for an old `.odt` password-protected document. I am using that password for other purposes so that I am sure that was the initial password of that odt document.

But I have modified very slightly that password for that document and now, because I haven't used that document for years, I have forgotten what exactly that change was. (It seemed so easy to remember when I did it because I was very sure I would not lose the "initial" password etc.)

Is there a way to "crack" that `.odt` password given the fact that I have a very similar one at hand?

Answer (score 8):

Try with [John The Ripper](https://github.com/openwall/john) extracting the hash using `libreoffice2john FILE > odt.hash`

Then you'll have to describe the best of your knowledge about the possible password before using `john` to brute force. (The less uncertainties you leave opened, the lower the processing power needed.)

If you can list the possible passwords into a file then simply

```
john --wordlist=the_pathname_of_list --fork=CORES odt.hash
```

But there are just [many other options](https://www.openwall.com/john/doc/OPTIONS.shtml) that you can use if you know much less such as, for example, iterating over all passwords consisting of numbers, as well as uppercase and lowercase letters, from 1 to 8 characters long:

```
john --fork=CORES -1=?l?u?d --mask='?1' --min-length=1 --max-length=8 odt.hash
```

At least, this will provide a good test of your cooling system :-)

Comment: ^^ This.... But you could elaborate a bit more: OP needs to put the original password in a file and use `--wordlist=file` and `--rules` option. Might also want to [adapt the rules file](https://www.openwall.com/john/doc/RULES.shtml).

Comment: and it highlights why "slight variations of the same complex password" are, in many scenarios, worse than having different easier passwords: You lose that password once, *all* your documents become quick to crack :/ And losing a password that you use for many things is much more likely (because you're not the one that loses password – it's the services you use getting your password).

Comment: `Invalid option parameter: "--fork=CORES"` --?

Comment: @cipricus : Simply replace CORES with the number of threads you accept running in //.

Comment: This odt is made with LOffice 7+, and it seems affected by [libreoffice2john does not work with LibreOffice 7.*](https://github.com/openwall/john/issues/4392). Testing with a file created with 5.3 version (appimage) I don´t see the error, so this might be it, which seems solved by [this](https://github.com/openwall/john/issues/4392#issuecomment-703296113) solution. Could you still bear with my ignorance and tell me what does that solution mean exactly?

Comment: In fact I seem to have solved that: replacing `3`with `4` in that line (and nothing else) but `john --wordlist=list.txt --fork=2 odt.hash` says `No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)`.

Comment: As an added bonus, use john's word mangling capabilities: `john --wordlist=input.txt --rules --stdout` to get common variations of your original password (e.g. "Myoriginalpassword1", "myoriginalpassword!", "myoriginalpassworD", and so on).